# UITableView is not smoothly when using downloading images

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am new in IOS development using Swift. I created 1 UITableView and displaying images after downloading data. But it is not smooth and some time images are displaying in wrong place when i am scrolling.

I am using [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) library for image downloading and displaying. Is there any fast library?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:HomePageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePage", for: indexPath) as! HomePageCell

    cell.configure( homeData[0], row: indexPath, screenSize: screenSize,
                    hometableview: self.homeTableView);

    return cell
}


import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class HomePageCell: UITableViewCell {



@IBOutlet weak var bannerImage: UIImageView!

func configure(_ homeData: HomeRequest, row: IndexPath, screenSize: CGRect, hometableview: UITableView) {


   let callData = homeData.banner_lead_stories[(row as NSIndexPath).row]
   let url = Constants.TEMP_IMAGE_API_URL + callData.lead_story[0].bg_image_mobile;


    if( !callData.lead_story[0].bg_image_mobile.isEmpty ) {

        if bannerImage?.image == nil {

            let range = url.range(of: "?", options: .backwards)?.lowerBound
            let u = url.substring(to: range!)

            Alamofire.request(u).responseImage { response in
                debugPrint(response)

                //print(response.request)
                // print(response.response)
                // debugPrint(response.result)

                if let image = response.result.value {
                    //   print("image downloaded: \(image)")

                    self.bannerImage.image = image;

                    self.bannerImage.frame  = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(screenSize.width), height: Int(screenSize.width/1.4))

                }
            }

        }

    } else {
        self.bannerImage.image = nil;
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: did you try Remoteimageview? https://github.com/adig/RemoteImageView

Comment: No i did not use. I am new in IOS using Swift. can we use it in Swift also?

Comment: yes, you can use it. i have already given link. many other library are available.

Comment: may you please help me to resolve that issue?

Comment: yes i will , why not? are you using cocoa pod?

Comment: @RahulRawat please accept the right answer so others who have the same problem can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be not smooth, because you need to cache your images and make a downloading process not in main thread(read about GCD).
For caching you can go two ways (atleast):

1) Make your own array of images where they will be cached

2) Use KingFisher for example [click](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). It will cache your images.
For example:

```
yourImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL) // next time, when you will use image with this URL, it will be taken from cache.
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use SDWebImage for downloading the image array and add a placeholder image for the time being in imageView. this is function

```
 public func sd_setImageWithURL(url: NSURL!, placeholderImage placeholder: UIImage!)
```

and it is as easy to use as

```
 myImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:image), placeholderImage:UIImage(named:"qwerty"))
```

**make sure to reset you imageView** in tableView delegate `cellforRowAtIndexpath` method by setting imageview image to nil

```
myImageView.image = nil
//now set image in imageView
myImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:image), placeholderImage:UIImage(named:"qwerty"))
```

this avoids the **image duplicating** and weird behave of **images as imageview** of every cell is being **reset before reusing**.
Github link -> https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 1):

You have to use multithreading.Only UI is set in main thread, downloading image in background is in another thread.By this way you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try SDWebImage library it will save images in catch automatically and your tableView will work smoothly.

Github link -> https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Install pod:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
```

Just import SDWebImage like:

```
@import SDWebImage
```

And use like this:

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

I used it in many live projects and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this extension to cache your images, and also don't forget to update any UI on the main thread.

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
extension UIImageView {
    func loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(_ URLString: String, placeHolder: UIImage?) {
        self.image = nil
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: NSString(string: URLString)) {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }  
        if let url = URL(string: URLString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                //print("RESPONSE FROM API: \(response)")
                if error != nil {
                    print("ERROR LOADING IMAGES FROM URL: \(error)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.image = placeHolder
                    }
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = data {
                        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                            imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: NSString(string: URLString))
                            self.image = downloadedImage
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```